# ifcase eats up letters

Tags: macros, pdftex, conditionals, debugging, output

I created a command that switches between `GCD` and `LCM`. However it has a side effect of erasing everything before the second visible character after the command. How can I fix this bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\GCDorLCM}[2]{\ifcase#1 GCD\or LCM\fi}
\newenvironment{GCDLCM_A}[3]{Find the \GCDorLCM{#1} of {#2} and {#3}.}{}
\newenvironment{GCDLCM_B}[2]{\GCDorLCM{#1}                      is maximized when \(x={#2}\).}{}

\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

\begin{GCDLCM_A}{1}{120}{84}
\end{GCDLCM_A}

\begin{GCDLCM_B}{0}{75}
\end{GCDLCM_B}

\end{document}
```

Expected output:

```
Find the LCM of 120 and 84.
GCD                      is maximized when x = 75.
```

Actual output:

```
Find the LCMf 120 and 84.
GCDs maximized when x = 75.
```

Answer (score 4):

Unrelated to `\ifcase` you have `\newcommand{\GCDorLCM}[2]` so define it with two arguments but you only use `#1` so `#2` (which is `o` here) is discarded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\GCDorLCM}[1]{\ifcase#1 GCD\or LCM\fi}
\newenvironment{GCDLCM_A}[3]{Find the \GCDorLCM{#1} of {#2} and {#3}.}{}
\newenvironment{GCDLCM_B}[2]{\GCDorLCM{#1}\hspace{4cm}is maximized when \(x={#2}\).}{}

\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

\begin{GCDLCM_A}{1}{120}{84}
\end{GCDLCM_A}

\begin{GCDLCM_B}{0}{75}
\end{GCDLCM_B}

\end{document}
```